# How to assign value to a column while iterating over a DataFrame using for eachrow

Tags: julia

I have the following code. It basically iterates over rows in a dataframe and tries to assign a value to column C.

I have tried to locate how to achieve this without success. I know that this sentence `r.C = i*100` is not correct, which would be the right one to assign a value to column C for each iterated row?

*Note that the question is a simplified example, in my real code I need to actually iterate over each row because the calculations are far more complex.*

File **main2.jl**:

```
struct MyStruct
    a::Int32
    b::Int32
    c::String
end

df = DataFrame( A=Int[], B=Int[] )
push!(df, [1, 10])
push!(df, [2, 20])
push!(df, [3, 30])

insertcols!(df, 3, :C => Int)


println(df)

i = 1
for r in eachrow(df)
    global i
    r.C = i*100
    i = i + 1
end
```

And I get:

```
julia> include("main2.jl")
|     A |     B |        C |
| Int64 | Int64 | DataType |
|-------|-------|----------|
|     1 |    10 |    Int64 |
|     2 |    20 |    Int64 |
|     3 |    30 |    Int64 |
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type DataType
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{S}, ::T<:(Union{CategoricalString{R}, CategoricalValue{T,R} where T} where R)) where {S, T<:(Union{CategoricalString{R}, CategoricalValue{T,R} where T} where R)} at /home/.../.julia/packages/CategoricalArrays/qcwgl/src/value.jl:91
  convert(::Type{T}, ::T) where T at essentials.jl:167
Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(::Array{DataType,1}, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:766
 [2] insert_single_entry!(::DataFrame, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64) at /home/.../.julia/packages/DataFrames/yH0f6/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:458
 [3] setindex! at /home/.../.julia/packages/DataFrames/yH0f6/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:497 [inlined]
 [4] setindex! at /home/.../.julia/packages/DataFrames/yH0f6/src/dataframerow/dataframerow.jl:106 [inlined]
 [5] setproperty!(::DataFrameRow{DataFrame,DataFrames.Index}, ::Symbol, ::Int64) at /home/.../.julia/packages/DataFrames/yH0f6/src/dataframerow/dataframerow.jl:129
 [6] top-level scope at /usr/home/.../main2.jl:23
 [7] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [8] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1094
 [9] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [10] include(::String) at ./client.jl:431
 [11] top-level scope at REPL[1]:1
in expression starting at /usr/home/.../main2.jl:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in

insertcols!(df, 3, :C => Int)

where you initialize the :C column with a type (Int) instead of an Int value, like 0. Changing this to

insertcols!(df, 3, :C => 0)

works.

Comment: What if I want to insert a new column which contains empty arrays of a given struct? I try: `df[!, :C] .= Vector{MyStruct}[]` but it does not work, it says `"LoadError: DiensionMismatch("array could not be broadcast to match destination")`

Comment: Your statement tries to put one MyStruct into each row of the C column. You could create a list of 3 MyStructs and that would fit nicely since you have 3 rows. The compiler can repeat an integer like 0, but it does not know how to make a default MyStruct to fill the columns when it is handed an empty array of MyStruct.

Comment: What I want is an empty Array of MyStruct in each row, not a MyStruct in each row. Or an "undefined" that can later be populated via `for r in eachrow(df)` with Arrays of MyStruct.

Comment: Harder. Create a dummy struct like m = MyStruct(0,0,""); then  df[!, :C] .= [[m, m], [m], [m]] should work. I wonder if you should not have some deeper dataframe structure instead though.

Comment: I think a canonical way to do it is `df.C = Vector{MyStruct}(undef, nrow(df))`. It is explicit what is going on (the code will be easy to read in 6 months time) and fast (i.e. you do not spend time/memory on allocating anything before you need it). You can also write e.g. `df[!, :C] .= MyStruct.(df.A, df.B, "some_string")` to populate the column in one shot (again - you can use broadcasting instead of for-loop in many cases).

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to add a column with a sentinel value to a `DataFrame` is just:

```
df[!, :C] .= 0
```

`insertcols!` is OK to use but typically it is employed when you want to insert a column in the middle of the `DataFrame` (not as the last column, what my example does).

Now the loop you have written at the end of your question can be stated as:

```
for (i, r) in enumerate(eachrow(df))
    r.C = i*100
end
```

which I would say is a more typical way to do it.

Finally you could have simply written:

```
df.C = 100 .* axes(df, 1)
```

to get the same effect. Note that the last statement could have been much more complex like:

```
df.C = @. 100 * $axes(df, 1) + df.A + sin(df.B)
```

or equivalently in this case

```
df.C = 100 * axes(df, 1) + df.A + sin.(df.B)
```

(in general - you can freely use broadcasting when working with data frames instead of loops)

Comment: Thanks, pls kindly see comment in Bill's answer in case you want to further elaborate for the case the column being added is an array of Structs (i.e. I intend to append variable length arrays of structs to column C, which I do not know is possible or not)